# Browsers caching AJAX headers

Tags: ajax, caching, cordova, http-headers

I have an application being developed in PhoneGap.  The REST API I'm using  ([Jive](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/rest/)) uses HTTP Basic Authentication to authenticate each request.  The header looks like:

```
Authorization: Basic Base64(username:password)
```

where `Base64()` represents a converting the parameter to base 64 encoding.  I have no trouble performing requests this way.  Once the user successfully logs in, indicated by a `200 OK` message, I save the encoded token and use it for all subsequent requests.  To implement logout, I set the stored token to an empty string:

```
api.token = "";
```

and then display the login page.  However, at this point, no matter what password you enter, the API returns a `200 OK` response as if the request came from the originally logged in user.

I have done everything but insert a proxy between my application and the server to verify that, in fact, the correct request header is getting set (with, for instance, in invalid password) including logging the token before it is used and inspecting with Safari Web Inspector and Google Developer Tools.  In each instance, the token is correctly reported to contain the password I entered, not the original one that was supposed to have been deleted.

In order to perform "remember me" functionality, I save the token in local storage.  If I kill the app and rebuild it with Xcode (for iOS) and then attempt to reopen the app (with the invalid token saved), I get all kinds of 403 errors indicating that it's using the token I entered with the invalid password.  So the process goes like this

1. Log in with valid username
2. Log out
3. Enter a valid username with a random password
4. User is treated as if password was valid
5. Kill the app and rebuild with Xcode
6. Open the app.  User is greeted with 403 errors.

I've also seen this happen in desktop versions of Safari and Chrome.

Any idea what's up??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't the browsers caching the headers (which really didn't make much sense to begin with).  Jive was sending a security cookie and using that and completely ignoring the `Authorization` header...